# how to use local pic in echarts?

Tags: echarts

I want to modify the 3Dsurface texture by `realistic material.normalTexture`

. When I don't use this(delete the underline code), the HTML page works well.

This png and HTML are in the same folder, so the path is right?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the [official example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=surface-leather&gl=1) the normal map can be defined like this:

```js
realisticMaterial: {
  // roughness: ROOT_PATH + '/data-gl/asset/leather/leather_roughness.jpg',
  normalTexture: ROOT_PATH + '/data-gl/asset/leather/leather_normal.jpg',
  // textureTiling: TILING
}
```

Try to [open Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#load) and take a look on the tab Network: maybe Echarts has failed to load texture.